# how to change property value of navbar in boostrap n sass

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

I have a nav bar in my page which has following CSS

```
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}
```

How do I change the value of `justify-content : start` value? When I write the change using SASS that does not work.

styles.scss

```
.navbarChange{
    @extend .navbar;
    justify-content:start;
    display:inline-flex;
}
```

navbarChange m replacing to navbar

how to we overwrite the property? Any help is appreciated

updated: my _variables.scss

```
.navbar
  { &.navbarChange
  {
    justify-content:start ;
    display:inline-flex;
 }
}
```

in my html

```
<nav class="navbar navbarChange navbar-dark bg-dark ">
        <a class="navbar navbarChange" href="#">
```

yet it doesn't work.

i have changed my styles.scss

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";

 @import "variables";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `!important`, which overrides properties. Like:

```
.navbarChange{
    @extend .navbar;
    justify-content: start!important;
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

Comment: Avoid using !important where possible. This can come round to bite you in the future when trying to overwrite other properties.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `!important` to overwrite properties, you want to make your CSS rules more specific than bootstraps.
Instead of putting the properties in `.navbarChange {}`, consider the selector `.navbar .navbarChange {}`.

Learn more about [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) on MDN

Comment: i found this a good one but then styling doesnt change doesnt get applied please c my updated code